# Remove rows of matrix on multiple conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, subset

This problem is best addressed by example.

Setup

```
Mat1 <- matrix(nrow =9, ncol =11)
colnames(Mat1) <- c("Name", "Strategy.Assets", "Jan.94", "Jan.95", "Jan.96", "Jan.97", "1", "2", "3","4", "5")
Mat1[,1] <- letters[1:9]
Mat1[,2] <- cbind(20,30,40,50,60,30,30,40,50)
Mat1[,3:6] <- rnorm(36,0,1)
Mat1[,7] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,8] <- c(0.95, 0.8, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,9] <- c(0.95,0.6,0.7,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,10] <- c(0.08, 0.09, 0.99, 0.93, 0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,11] <- c(0.09,0.01,0.04,0.97, 0.80,0,0,0,0)

data.frame(Mat1)
```

treat columns "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" as the beginning of the correlation matrix (it should be 9 by 9 but i am only showing the first 6 columns).

For each row in columns 1 to 6, i need to identify if there is a value >= 0.95. If there is, i need to know the position. In this case the value 0.95 appears in entry m= 1, n=2 of the correlation matrix. I then need to go to the column "strategy assets" and compare the values in rows 1 and 2 (in this case 20 and 30). After this, I need to omit the row with the lower value (row 1 as 20 is less than 30). After removing one row, I need to proceed to the next row in the correlation matrix - we see that in row 2, there are no values that are at least equal to 0.95. We then proceed to the third row. We then see 0.99 >0.95 occurs in position m=3, n=4. We then go to "strategy assets" and compare values in row 3 and 4. In row 3 strategy assets = 40, and row 4 =50. Thus we omit row 3. We then proceed to row 4 of the correlation matrix. in position 4,5 0.99 occurs. We then need to compare rows 4 and 5 in strategy assets. We see that row 5 =60, and row 4=50 and so need to omit row4.

I need to repeat this process for all rows in the correlation matrix.

Notice that entry (1,3) of the correlation matrix also equals 0.95. However, as row1 has already been removed (from the first iteration), i do not need the loop to continue running in this case.

```
  > data.frame(Mat1)
  Name Strategy.Assets             Jan.94             Jan.95             Jan.96              Jan.97 X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1    a              20   2.95438832384095  0.322838398649362  0.265489849080971   -1.26762589628627  0 0.95 0.95 0.08 0.09
2    b              30 -0.231467724347497   1.36209337396348  0.244352997300369   0.147019042483708  0  0.8  0.6 0.09 0.01
3    c              40 -0.725388339795491 0.0813983643917171  -0.50418751522557   0.802967414744253  0    0  0.7 0.99 0.04
4    d              50 -0.120645568994363    1.7770242881308 -0.798437656907533    1.03842921924565  0    0    0 0.93 0.97
5    e              60  0.818447801042692 -0.767858384307916  -1.23187047713004 -0.0779863946287645  0    0    0    0  0.8
6    f              30 -0.231572883434978  0.266559660007751  0.720829574412722 -0.0207732265889516  0    0    0    0    0
7    g              30  0.444651868913969  0.832322051653509 -0.538333881677844   0.291130047037627  0    0    0    0    0
8    h              40   2.00827324376109  0.775006479679076 0.0323592399331455   -2.33121256833447  0    0    0    0    0
9    i              50 -0.368493048065977   1.30727697822673 -0.446402751994181 -0.0616057412430855  0    0    0    0    0
```

then my desired output is:

```
output <- data.frame(rbind(Mat1[2,1:6], Mat1[5:9,1:6]))
output

  Name Strategy.Assets             Jan.94             Jan.95             Jan.96              Jan.97
1    b              30 -0.231467724347497   1.36209337396348  0.244352997300369   0.147019042483708
2    e              60  0.818447801042692 -0.767858384307916  -1.23187047713004 -0.0779863946287645
3    f              30 -0.231572883434978  0.266559660007751  0.720829574412722 -0.0207732265889516
4    g              30  0.444651868913969  0.832322051653509 -0.538333881677844   0.291130047037627
5    h              40   2.00827324376109  0.775006479679076 0.0323592399331455   -2.33121256833447
6    i              50 -0.368493048065977   1.30727697822673 -0.446402751994181 -0.0616057412430855
```

I need to be able to apply this function to matrices in a list. Every matrix in the list has a different number of rows, and hence a different number of columns. However the first 6 columns are always the same. Essentially, the 'names' variable increases (it could be from a to z), causing the correlation matrix to increase.(would be 26 by 26 in this case).

Comment: As you are keeping data in matrix all the values in it is converted to character because of `Name` column. Do you want to keep it as matrix or convert it to a dataframe? Also in this example only one row is removed can you add a more detailed example where multiple rows are deleted so it is easier to understand.

Comment: Why do you want to work with matrix? looking at the various types of variables, it seems to me that a `data.frame`, `data.table` or `tibble` is more appropriate...

Comment: One second. I'll frame it as a data.frame and extend the example. I'm still learning R at the moment.

Comment: "_I then need to go to the column "strategy assets" and compare the values for 1 and 2 (in this case 20 and 30)._" I don't quite follow you on this: What values for 1 and 2 of strategy.assets? columns `1` and `2` don't have 20 and 30, and if I filter the data for `2` >= 0.95, I only get strategy.assets equal to 20

Comment: @PavoDive editted. It was meant to read in "rows 1 and 2" of column "strategy assets"

Comment: hmmm... It seems to me that converting to a `data.frame` wasn't enough... I suggest you make your data _tidy_. In tidy data, each row is an observation and each column is a variable. By what you say, I think each row **isn't** an observation. Perhaps if you split the data, you can have two tables that are tidy? (you can use joins afterwards)

Comment: No no you are correct. Each row is an observation and each column is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, one way could be to first find out row and column index where the value is greater than equal to 0.95 for the correlation columns using `which`. For every row and column pair, we find out the corresponding minimum value and remove that row from original `Mat1`.

```
mat <- which(Mat1[, as.character(1:5)] >= 0.95, arr.ind = TRUE)
Mat1[-unique(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x[which.min(Mat1$Strategy.Assets[x])])), ]


#  Name Strategy.Assets      Jan.94      Jan.95     Jan.96     Jan.97 1   2   3    4    5
#2    b              30 -0.02101158  1.27504998 -0.9534582 -0.6917499 0 0.8 0.6 0.09 0.01
#5    e              60 -0.88500700 -1.19165574 -1.6309657  0.6183648 0 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.80
#6    f              30 -0.45072999 -0.04698659  0.7462178  0.5858741 0 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00
#7    g              30  1.29131284 -1.60004027 -0.9681269  0.9595044 0 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00
#8    h              40  0.37883959 -1.11536574 -0.3041997 -0.8202406 0 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00
#9    i              50  1.50068308  0.89465888  0.6646096  0.4433313 0 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00
```

**data**

```
Mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =9, ncol =11))
colnames(Mat1) <- c("Name", "Strategy.Assets", "Jan.94", "Jan.95", "Jan.96", 
                 "Jan.97", "1", "2", "3","4", "5")

Mat1[,1] <- letters[1:9]
Mat1[,2] <- c(20,30,40,50,60,30,30,40,50)
Mat1[,3:6] <- rnorm(36,0,1)
Mat1[,7] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,8] <- c(0.95, 0.8, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,9] <- c(0.95,0.6,0.7,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,10] <- c(0.08, 0.09, 0.99, 0.93, 0,0,0,0,0)
Mat1[,11] <- c(0.09,0.01,0.04,0.97, 0.80,0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: this is amazing dude! thanks so much. I'll mark this as the answer later (other people might have other ideas). But i can work with this for now! Thanks mate